# Снова запятые...

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли здесь ставить запятую при перечислении? Кто-нибудь может скинуть ссылку на правило? И как это называется: обстоятельства или несогласованные определения?

Наша компания имеет значительный опыт работы в области замены участков действующих трубопроводов, в том числе и с установленной трубопроводной арматурой, без остановки транспорта продукта (,) с использованием технологий и оборудования компании T. D. Williamson SA.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаемый вариант:

Наша компания имеет значительный опыт работы в области замены участков действующих трубопроводов с использованием технологий и оборудования компании T. D. Williamson SA,
в том числе и с установленной трубопроводной арматурой, без остановки транспорта продукта.

Это оборот со значением включения, состоящий из двух однородных обстоятельств образа действия (как?). Оборот "с использованием технологий и оборудования компании T. D. Williamson SA" по отношению к ним не является однородным, поэтому его лучше перенести в другое место.

Comment: Спасибо. Но все же, если оставить, как есть, то нужна ли запятая?

Comment: Запятая нужна в любом случае, но в приведенном варианте невозможно различить однородные и неоднородные обстоятельства, а это затрудняет понимание текста. Надо бы хотя бы как-то их разделить, например: "Наша компания имеет значительный опыт работы в области замены участков действующих трубопроводов, в том числе и с установленной трубопроводной арматурой, без остановки транспорта продукта,  при  использовании технологий и оборудования компании T. D. Williamson SA".

Answer (score 0):

Запятая закрывает перечисление, далее следует причастие.

Comment: "С использованием технологий и оборудования компаний" - где здесь причастие? Причастия в этом предложении - это "установленной" и "действующих".

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, насколько актуально, но отвечу.

Запятая нужна уже потому, что надо как-то закрыть "вложенное" уточнение *без остановки транспорта продукта*. Как вариант можно убрать и открывающую запятую, тогда определения станут неоднородными, но, хотя смысл и не изменится, зрительное восприятие сильно усложнится.

> "С использованием технологий и оборудования компаний" - где здесь
>   причастие?

@Alenka, Здесь и **перечисления-то** как такового нет. У Сержа опять какое-то своё понимание смысла, он, видимо, считает все сказанное тремя разными способами. Но "без остановки транспорта" и "с установленной аппаратурой" - это, очевидно, всё про один и тот же метод. Запятые ставятся по совершенно иным мотивам. София все правильно разобрала, хотя перенос "с использованием..." может сам по себе быть спорным.